# Passing binary data over a querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, handler

I am building a system for the HR department in the office I work.  This will be an enhancement to an existing project/staff management application we have developed.  There is some existing functionality that will handle a document like the below.  This is all C#/ASP.NET based.

```
 //Check for document being available
            if (ed.ContentType == null || ed.DocumentData == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                strExtenstion = ed.ContentType.ToString();
                strFilename = ed.Filename.ToString();
                docData = ed.DocumentData;

                byte[] bytFile = (byte[])docData.ToArray();

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;

                if (strExtenstion == ".doc")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                }
                else if (strExtenstion == ".docx")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                }
                else if (strExtenstion == ".pdf")
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                }

                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + strFilename.ToString());
                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

                Page.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytFile, 0, bytFile.Length - 1);  //Drop final byte to enable inclusion of MS Office 2007 types
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();

                Response.End();
            }
```

We have a class for each type of document that could be handled such as; News docs, Expense files, Business Procedures and I have just created a class that will handle staff appraisals/reviews.  I would like be to able to create a generic document handler that will **not rely** on invoking an instance of a class depending on a query string value to determine the object.  We simply pass in a document ID with the querystring to determin which class methods to expose.  One idea that I have was to leave out the object identity querystring but actually pass in the binary document data and mime type so the response will tell the browser which application that needs to be opened on the client machine.  This is an internal intranet system I should point out and my experience is very limited so forgive any idiocy/poor thinking habits.

My questions are;

Is thinking about passing binary data over a querystring a bad idea?

Is there a beter way to build a generic document handle that will open the relevant application on the local machine(MS Office and PDF mime types)?

Thanks

Comment: An query is limited with its length, and its not a good practice o send binary data as a query string, and if your data contains a null character your data would not be complete, if you wanted to pass any data then you could use a session

Comment: What's wrong with good old POST?

Comment: @BobTodd In this instance, the page has a list view control with inormation about the document, on the SelectedIndexChanged event is does a Response.Redirect("MyLink.aspx?docID=x&category=y") would POST be something I could implement.  There is no form on the page. - JohnnBlade, thanks for the suggestion of using session.  That may be a good solution.  No answer?

Comment: you should just pass document id to some page lets say DownloadDocument.aspx?ID=123 and in the page load method of this page you should do what you are doing in above code. and in listview control you should use hyperlink(no postback buttons)